# TypeError: "undefined is not a function"

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, undefined, kineticjs

So I am trying to create a custom shape using kinetic.js but I have ran into a problem.
I am calling a function on click that should display a new drawing but I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Here is the function code:

```
    function helpShow(){
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'SkateboardCanvas',
        width: 800,
        height: 500
    });

    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var helpMenu = new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: function(context) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(600,500);
        context.lineTo(600,450);
        context.moveTo(200,500);
        context.lineTo(600,500);
        // x1, y1, x2, y2, radius
        console.log(context);
        context.arcTo(600,350,550,350,50);
        context.lineTo(250,350);
        context.moveTo(200,500);
        context.lineTo(200,450);
        context.arcTo(200,350,250,350,50);
        context.closePath();
        context.fillStrokeShape(this);
    },
        fill: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
    });

    layer.add(helpMenu);
    console.log(layer);
    console.log(stage);
    stage.add(layer);
}
```

The line it is throwing the error on is:

```
context.arcTo(600,350,550,350,50);
```

And here is the console logs which shows everything is defined.

> Kinetic.Layer {nodeType: "Layer", canvas: Kinetic.SceneCanvas, hitCanvas: Kinetic.HitCanvas, children: Kinetic.Collection[1], _id: 2…}
>    creatorCanvas.js:86
>
> Kinetic.Stage {nodeType: "Stage", children: Kinetic.Collection[0], _id: 1, eventListeners: Object, attrs: Object…}
>    creatorCanvas.js:87
>
> Kinetic.SceneContext {canvas: Kinetic.SceneCanvas, _context: CanvasRenderingContext2D, _fillColor: function, _fillPattern: function, _fillLinearGradient: function…}

Also the canvas and context is defined at the top of the JavaScript file as follows:

```
var canvas = $("#SkateboardCanvas");
var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
```

I am relatively new to it all so any help/explanation on why this is happening would be great or if I am being a complete newb I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context you're given by the Kinetic.Shape is actually a wrapper around an actual canvas context.

The wrapper you're given does not support the path context.arcTo command.

You have several workarounds:

1. Refactor your shape to use context.quadraticCurveTo instead of arcTo.
2. Replace your Kinetic.Shape with a Kinetic.Image that uses an offscreen html canvas element as its image source.  This way you can use native canvas's .arcTo command on the offscreen canvas.

Here's a demo of #2:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/u69A8/

```
var myShape=new Kinetic.Image({
    x:10,
    y:10,
    image:drawTab(),
});
layer.add(myShape);
layer.draw();

function drawTab(){
    var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width=400;
    canvas.height=150;
    context.save();
    context.translate(-200,-350);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(600,500);
    context.lineTo(600,450);
    context.moveTo(200,500);
    context.lineTo(600,500);
    // x1, y1, x2, y2, radius
    context.arcTo(600,350,550,350,50);
    context.lineTo(250,350);
    context.moveTo(200,500);
    context.lineTo(200,450);
    context.arcTo(200,350,250,350,50);
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStyle="red";
    context.fill();
    context.restore();
    return(canvas);
}
```